# How do I hand over lists to classes and work with a copy of that list inside an instance of the class

Tags: c#, list, constructor

please see code example below:

```
Main Program:

List<MyObject> _listofmyobjects = new();

for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
{
        _listofmyobjects.Add(new MyObject(i));
}

var test = new Test(_list);


public class Test
{
    List<MyObject>_obj = new(); //-> Variant 1
    List<MyObject>_obj;         //-> Variant 2

        public Test(List<MyObject> arglist)
        {
        
            _obj = arglist;
        
        }
        
        public void DoSth()
        {
        
            //Work with _obj inside instance of Test, get and set properties of _obj
        
        }
   
}
```

It is not 100% clear to me what the difference between Variant 1 and Variant 2 is.
Both variants work.

But I want to make sure that inside class Test I only work with a copy of the list handed over via the constructor.

It is also unclear if I have to delete odr clear the list somewhere in the code or reset it via _obj = new().

Comment: Both variants are identical and in both cases _obj refers to exactly the same list as _list. Please make sure if you want to have a copy of the list containing the same objects, or a list containing copies of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

> It is not 100% clear to me what the difference between Variant 1 and Variant 2 is. Both variants work.

Variant 1 assigns a new List to `_obj`, whereas variant 2 doesn't.

As you say, the behaviour is identical anyway, because the List passed into the constructor is assigned to the `_obj` variable regardless, so version 1 is completely unnecessary.

> But I want to make sure that inside class Test I only work with a copy of the list handed over via the constructor.

In that case, you should make a copy in the constructor:

```
public Test(List<MyObject> arglist)
{
    _obj = new(arglist);
}
```

The constructor used here copies the items from `arglist` into a new list and assigns that new list to `_obj`.

---

As an aside, it's preferable to request a less specific type in the constructor of `Test`. If you're simply copying the item into a new List, then `IEnumerable<MyObject>` gives more flexibility to the consumer. That way an array, set etc. can be used instead.

Comment: I understand that in case I use a reference (not a copy) like in Variant 1 and 2 I work with the values in the list _listofmyobjects created in the main program. Consequently this means that if I change values of _obj inside an instance of my class Test this would also change the values in  _listofmyobjects. Is that understanding correct ? If yes, what happens, if _listofmyobjects gets destroyed e.g. by GC or changes outside of Test-Instance while I am working on in in _obj ? So according to my understanding I MUST work with a copy.

Comment: Variant 1 is redundant, because you re-assign `_obj` in the constructor anyway. Making a copy of the list means that any changes to the list itself, i.e. items added or removed within `Test` won't be reflected back to `_listofmyobjects` in the main program. However, if you make a change to a `MyObject` item within the list e.g. updating a property value, then those will be reflected, because they are reference types.